# Laravel resource controller difference between edit and update

Tags: rest, laravel

In laravel when using `Route::resource()` the controller [contains 7 methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers). I am unsure what the differences are between the `edit` and `update` methods / resources.

```
GET         /resource/{resource}/edit   edit    resource.edit
PUT/PATCH   /resource/{resource}        update  resource.update
```

In my understanding of REST, it seems laravels `update` implementation is fairly standard while the `edit` route I can't see to think of a scenario to use it when returning resources as JSON.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The difference is that `edit` is used to return the HTML form that is used to edit the resource values (notice that it responds to `GET` requests), while `update`is the "action" that the edit form will be submitting to, and it responds to `PUT` or `PATCH` requests.

Comment: so is this function useless if returning JSON as per a classic API?

Comment: You can say that, after all if you don't need it just don't use it.

Comment: thanks, seems the `create` methods fall under this too